# Invalid Identifier when using join

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to join two tables with a left join but, the next error comes out:

*error line 7 at position 11 invalid identifier 'VAR01'*

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
    RE.VAR02,
    *
FROM TABLE01 CU
LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
        ON VAR01 = RE.VAR02
LIMIT 10
```

I know that the Invalid identifiers implies to me something is named incorrectly, but all the variables that Im using are correct

Comment: AS per Lukasz, your SQL is valid snowflake syntax, and thus "if you are experiencing" this problem, it implies you are not on Snowflake, and therefore should remove that tag. If you are on Snowflake, you should remove the SQL tag, and this is not valid ANSI SQL, and most DB's will complain about it. Thus the non-Lukasz answers are correct in the context of not a Snowflake DB. I hope this help frame the problem with your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE01(X TEXT, Y TEXT, Z TEXT)
AS    SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c' 
UNION SELECT 'x', 'y', 'z' 
UNION SELECT 'i', 'j', 'k';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE02(VAR02 TEXT) 
AS    SELECT 'abc' 
UNION SELECT 'ijk';

SELECT 
    CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
    RE.VAR02,
    *
FROM TABLE01 CU
LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
        ON VAR01 = RE.VAR02
LIMIT 10;
```

[image]

Query profile:

```
EXPLAIN USING TABULAR
SELECT 
    CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
    RE.VAR02,
    *
FROM TABLE01 CU
LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
        ON VAR01 = RE.VAR02
LIMIT 10;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were missing the alias from your first table before the column name.  Your join was trying to join on

```
ON VAR01 = RE.VAR02
```

You need the table alias before the VAR01, see below:

```
SELECT 
    CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
    RE.VAR02,
    *
FROM TABLE01 CU
LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
        ON CU.VAR01 = RE.VAR02
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ON clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause, so the alias VAR01 does not yet exist at the time the ON clause is being evaluated.

You can do it either way :

```
1) Repeat the expression in the ON clause :

    SELECT 
        CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
        RE.VAR02,
        *
    FROM TABLE01 CU
    LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
            ON CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z = RE.VAR02
    LIMIT 10;

2) Using Subquery:

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
      CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z AS VAR01,
      RE.VAR02,
      *
  FROM TABLE01 CU
  LEFT JOIN TABLE02 RE
          ON CU.X||CU.Y||CU.Z = RE.VAR02
  LIMIT 10
) subquery;
```